# Is it possible to group kendo grid columns with two column names?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid and I have to group columns by two column names which have aggregates defined.

Ex:

```
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectOne',
            'HFB': 'Eating',
            'week1': '10',
            'week2': '10',
            'week3': '10',
            'week4': '10',
            'week5': '10',
},
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectOne',
            'HFB': 'Eating',
            'week1': '10',
            'week2': '10',
            'week3': '10',
            'week4': '10',
            'week5': '10',
},
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectTwo',
            'HFB': 'Decoration',
            'week1': '10',
            'week2': '10',
            'week3': '10',
            'week4': '10',
            'week5': '10',
},
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectTwo',
            'HFB': 'Decoration',
            'week1': '10',
            'week2': '10',
            'week3': '10',
            'week4': '10',
            'week5': '10',
}
```

and the columns object is like the following

```
 group: {
                field: 'Type',
                aggregates: [
                    { field: "week1", aggregate: "sum" },
                    { field: "week2", aggregate: "sum" },
                    { field: "week3", aggregate: "sum" },
                    { field: "week4", aggregate: "sum" },
                    { field: "week5", aggregate: "sum" },
       ]
}
```

now I want to group the columns also with the 'HFB' property and the and the result should look like the following

```
Eating -> ProjectOne
Decoration -> ProjectTwo
```

I tried changing the columns array into object and values in the array as objects, it didn't work because aggregates is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column.groupHeaderColumnTemplate` in order to have proper aggregates at each grouping tier.

Example ([Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/AQExaQUm)):

The example uses some tricks

- hidden span containing a sequence number
- hide column added to grid in order to set the `title` and `groupHeaderTemplate`

in order to get the *month* groups in the data order.  The default is that the grid will sort the groups in ascending value order.

```
  <style>
  .hidden {display:none}
  </style>
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    data = [
      { region: 'A', month: 'Jan', week: 1, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Jan', week: 2, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Jan', week: 3, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Jan', week: 4, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Feb', week: 1, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Feb', week: 2, sales:  20 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Feb', week: 3, sales:  30 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Feb', week: 4, sales:  40 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Mar', week: 1, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Mar', week: 2, sales:  50 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Mar', week: 3, sales:  60 },
      { region: 'A', month: 'Mar', week: 4, sales:  60 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Jan', week: 1, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Jan', week: 2, sales:  20 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Jan', week: 3, sales:  30 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Jan', week: 4, sales:  40 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Feb', week: 1, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Feb', week: 2, sales:  60 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Feb', week: 3, sales:  70 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Feb', week: 4, sales:  80 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Mar', week: 1, sales:  10 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Mar', week: 2, sales: 100 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Mar', week: 3, sales: 110 },
      { region: 'B', month: 'Mar', week: 4, sales: 120 },
     ];
    
     function z7(n) {
       return ("0000000" + n).slice(-7);
     }
    
     var month = 'zzz', ix = 0;
    
     for (var index = 0; index<data.length; index++) {
       var item = data[index];
       if (item.month != month) {
         month = item.month;
         ix++;
       }
       item.monthgroup = "<span class=hidden>" + z7(ix) + "</span>" + month;
     }
    
     $("#grid").kendoGrid({  
        dataSource: {
          data: data,
          group: [
                        { field: "region", aggregates: [ {field:"sales", aggregate:"sum" }] },
                        { field: "monthgroup",  aggregates: [ {field:"sales", aggregate:"sum" }] },
          ],
          sort: { field: 'mon' }
        },
        columns: [
          { field: 'monthgroup', title: 'month', groupHeaderTemplate: "#=value#" },
          { field: 'week', width: '5em' },
          { field: 'sales', width: '6em', groupHeaderColumnTemplate: "#=sum#" },
          { field: 'sizebalance', title: ' ' }
        ],
        height: 750,
        scrollable: true,
        groupable: true,
      });  
    
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.hideColumn(0);
  </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Richard, this is kind of helpful, but I want only one month under each region. Is that possible?. I mean under region-A I only need 'jan' and under region-B I only need 'feb' and under region-C I only need 'mar'. Is that possible? By the way thanks for the answer.

Comment: What appears in the second tier is wholly dependent on the data.  Either ensure the rows for a region contain only information for a single month, or if the data is more 'full' , like in the example, you could instead apply a data source filter (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the aggregates array for each grouping variable (and change grouping from object to array to specify a group nesting of two columns) and then render them in a `groupFooterTemplate`.  There is a side effect of the grid displaying two adjacent footer rows (the second repeating the first) when there is more than one grouping column.  The second row can be hidden using an adjacent CSS selector `tr.k-group-footer + tr.k-group-footer {display:none}` .

Example grid (image):
[image]

Example code ([Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/oQuFiduw/3)):

I changed the week data values from strings containing a number to just number.

```
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <style>
    tr.k-group-footer + tr.k-group-footer { display: none }
  </style>
  <script>
    data = [
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectOne',
            'HFB': 'Eating',
            'week1': 10,
            'week2': 20,
            'week3': 30,
            'week4': 40,
            'week5': 50,
},
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectOne',
            'HFB': 'Eating',
            'week1': 10,
            'week2': 11,
            'week3': 12,
            'week4': 13,
            'week5': 14,
},
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectTwo',
            'HFB': 'Decoration',
            'week1': 21,
            'week2': 22,
            'week3': 23,
            'week4': 24,
            'week5': 25,
},
{
            'Name': "Test",
            'Type': 'ProjectTwo',
            'HFB': 'Decoration',
            'week1': 10,
            'week2': 10,
            'week3': 10,
            'week4': 10,
            'week5': 10,
}    
];

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930100/
//   is-it-possible-to-group-kendo-grid-columns-with-two-column-names
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({  
        dataSource: {
          data: data,
          group: [
                        { field: "HFB",
                aggregates: [
                { field: "week1", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week2", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week3", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week4", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week5", aggregate: "sum" }
                    ]
            }, 
                        { field: "Type",
                aggregates: [
                { field: "week1", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week2", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week3", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week4", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "week5", aggregate: "sum" }
                    ]
            }
          ],
        },
        columns: [
          { field: 'Name', width: '5em' },
/*        'Type', */
/*              'HFB', */
          {field: 'week1', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", width: "4em" },
          {field: 'week2', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", width: "4em" },
          {field: 'week3', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", width: "4em" },
          {field: 'week4', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", width: "4em" },
          {field: 'week5', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", width: "4em" },
          {field: 'sizebalance', title: ' ' }
        ],
        height: 750,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        groupable: true,
      });
    });    
  </script>
```

Image of footer rows if the CSS is not used to hide extra one.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I just used 'groupFooterTemplate' to generate another row.

Comment: Hi @Richard, you used groupFooterTemplate so that the aggregations are done at the grid bottom. But I need aggregations to be done at the header level. That means, following the both the group headers like the following. First row: HFB-Decoration-sum-sum-sum-sum...,. Second row: Project Two-sum-sum-sum-sum.....